# React useEffect not triggered

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

My useEffect code looks like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      setBalance(user.user_balance);
      console.log("user.user_balance");

      console.log(user.user_balance);
    }
  }, [user]);
```

Full code : https://pastebin.com/CP6sLNQZ

The useEffect is supposed to get triggered every time user (user_balance) gets updated in the database but it is not getting triggered. User is a props and it is passed from redux to the component.

The action for updating the balance is here:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { returnErrors } from "./errorActions";
import { UPDATE_BALANCE_SUCCESS } from "./types";

//update balance
export const updateBalance = ({ email, user_balance }) => (dispatch) => {
  // Headers
  const config = {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  };

  // Request body
  const body = JSON.stringify({ email, user_balance });

  axios
    .post("/api/users/updatebalance", body, config)
    .then((res) =>
      dispatch({
        type: UPDATE_BALANCE_SUCCESS,
        payload: { email, user_balance },
      })
    )
    .catch((err) =>
      dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status))
    );
};
```

The reducer:

```
import { UPDATE_BALANCE_SUCCESS } from "../actions/types";

const initalState = {
  email: null,
  user_balance: null,
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_BALANCE_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        email: action.payload.email,
        user_balance: action.payload.user_balance,
      };
  }
}
```

And the end-point:

```
// @route       POST api/users/updatebalance
// @description Update user balance
// @access      Public
router.post("/updatebalance", (req, res) => {
  const { email, user_balance } = req.body;

  User.findOneAndUpdate(
    { email },
    { $inc: { user_balance: user_balance } },
    function (err, result) {
      if (err) {
        res.send(err);
      } else {
        res.send(result);
      }
    }
  );
});
```

Also where auth comes from:

This is the auth reducer: https://pastebin.com/upHdvtiF

These are the actions: https://pastebin.com/Ajp7S1Yi

And this is the end point: https://pastebin.com/NwCHCitY

I got a log in and register page and once a user gets registered auth gets created. In the actions link you can see the login and register action.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Hooks, setTimeout in useEffect not triggering until end, because of state updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62641564/react-hooks-settimeout-in-useeffect-not-triggering-until-end-because-of-state)

Comment: what if u use auth as the dependency?

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial it doesn't get triggered even when auth is used as the dependency.

Comment: Since you are using redux, why do you pass `user` as a `props` and not using `useSelector` hook from `react-redux` to access it directly? Also, you don't pass `user` to the child component as props in your detailed code.

Comment: can we see where `auth` comes from since it's related to where `user` comes from. The `useEffect` will  not triggerd even after an update occurs cause the `user` don't have any changes occurs to it.

Comment: can you update the question with how you get the user with store?

Comment: Updated my post, you can have a look now

Comment: given your code + links, it looks like you have a reducer state related to auth (which containes user) and another reducer state related to user data, like balance and email. you are mapping user from auth state, though your `updateBalance` updates a complete different state not related to `auth.user`.

Comment: @buzatto Oh, i understand. How should I go about solving this as I'm a bit about what should I do next?

Comment: first remove user duplication. decide if you want to keep user data at auth or at another user state, but not at both. then update your reducers and actions to reflect your decision. finally, your user's map state to props should extract user from the exact reducer state which holds user data.

Comment: Managed to make it work, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to add the user layer

```
const initalState = {
  user: {
     email: null,
     user_balance: null,
  }
};
```

and the reducer

```
export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_BALANCE_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        user: {
           ...state.user,
           email: action.payload.email,
           user_balance: action.payload.user_balance,
        }
      };
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't really change anything. UseEffect still won't detect when user gets updated.

Comment: It is not possible, then there might be multiple redux stores for you. better if you can prepare a codepen